# Dispatching event from Model with custom event key

Tags: laravel, laravel-events

I'm currently rebuilding an application and I currently have this in observer

```
public function updated(Lead $lead) {
    
    if ( $lead->isDirty('status') && $lead->status === 'rejected') {
        LeadRejected::dispatch($lead);
    }
        
}
```

I'm removing the use of observer and want to dispatch the event directly from the model

something like;

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'updated' => LeadUpdated::class,
];
```

I'd like to know if its possible to create a custom event key (model's lifecycle) I can hook the `LeadRejected` event

something like

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'rejected' => LeadRejected::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar in Laravel which helps you achieve your goal. Here is an example:

**app\Model\Lead.php**

```
protected $observables = ['rejected'];

protected static function booted()
{
    static::updated(function ($model) {
         $this->fireModelEvent('rejected', false);
    });
}
```

**app\Observers\LeadObserver:**

```
public function rejected(Lead $lead)
{
   //do something.
}
```

Ref: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-custom-model-events-in-laravelexample.html